# Android: LayoutInflater - adding a View

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, view, layout-inflater

I have the following code, see below. I want to add a View programmatically to the inflated layout - because the View's size, I want to add to the layout, depends on another View's size which I  am receiving in the ViewTree Observer (the on pre draw listener of the ViewTree Observer gives you the chance to get the size of a layout item when it uses "fill_parent", therefore it has to be pre drawn to get the size).

How can I do this? LayoutInflater doesn't provide a method for adding a View. Maybe I only need a hint, I know how to create Views programmatically - but how do I add them in such case?

PS: The getView method is used for a ListView.

```
 @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            int type = getItemViewType(position);
            if (convertView == null) {
                switch (type) {
                    case TYPE_ITEM0:
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.event_details_headline, null);
                        TextView toptext = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
                        toptext.setText(mData.get(0).getTitle());


                        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.flyer);
                        AwesomeActivity.imageLoader.DisplayRoundedImage(mData.get(0).getFlyerURL(), imageView);


                        final int[] flyerheight = {0};
                        final int[] flyerwidth = {0};
                        final ImageView border = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.border);
                        ViewTreeObserver vto = imageView.getViewTreeObserver();
                        vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
                            public boolean onPreDraw() {

                                flyerheight[0] = imageView.getMeasuredHeight();
                                flyerwidth[0] = imageView.getMeasuredWidth();

                                // Here I want to add an ImageView based on flyerWidth and flyerHeight

                                return true;
                            }
                        });

                        break;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the outer most class or viewgroup used in 'event_details_headline.xml' file and typecast it to a variable. Views can only be added to ViewGroups or its subclasses. Suppose the linearlayout is the outermost view group in ur xml, ur inflate code should look like

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)mInflater.inflate(
        R.layout.event_details_headline, null);
layout.addView(YOUR VIEW);
convertView = layout;
```

This should work.